# How to cut an overlong PDF page in a series of A4 PDF pages with ImageMagick

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, pdf-generation

I have an overlong PDF containing text and image elements. Here an example:

[image: Overlong PDF]

How can I split this page into a PDF with mutiple A4 pages where the first pages contains the top bit, the next page what's shown underneath and so on until the last page which holds the leftover at the bottom.

When I just 'print' the PDF to an new PDF (e.g. in Preview on macOS) in full-width mode *only the middle* of the input page is saved.

Can I do this easily with ImageMagick?

---

ps: If generating all pages is too difficult, having just the first page containing the top of the input PDF would be OK too.

Comment: What is your Imagemagick version and platform? Can you zip your PDF and upload it or post to some free hosting service and put the link in your question?

Comment: I am using both IM versions 6 & 7, but your answer covers both. Pretty cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PDF width at 72 dpi is 595, then in Imagemagick 6, you can do

```
convert image.pdf -crop 595x842 +repage +adjoin result.pdf
```

If using Imagemagick 7, you can do

```
magick image.pdf -crop "%[papersize:a4]" +repage +adjoin result.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks. I used your principle, I just ended up increasing the density fourfold to have the text sharper: `convert -density 288 -trim input.pdf -crop 2380x3368 +repage +adjoin result.pdf`